# How do i set the size of a panel to the size of a window, even if the window size changes?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

This is my code. I would like to set the size of the box the ball bounces in to that of the window size, even if the window is resized by the user, such as making the window restored, or dragging it to a size.
Thanks a lot.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**
 * One ball bouncing inside a rectangular box. 
 * All codes in one file. Poor design!
 */
// Extends JPanel, so as to override the paintComponent() for custom rendering codes. 
public class BouncingBallSimple extends JPanel {
// Container box's width and height
private final int BOX_WIDTH = 700;
private final int BOX_HEIGHT = 700;

// Ball's properties
private float ballRadius = 15; // Ball's radius
private float ballX = ballRadius + 50; // Ball's center (x, y)
private float ballY = ballRadius + 20; 
private float ballSpeedX = 60;   // Ball's speed for x and y
private float ballSpeedY = 60;

private static final int UPDATE_RATE = 30; // Number of refresh per second

/** Constructor to create the UI components and init game objects. */
public BouncingBallSimple() {
  this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT));

  // Start the ball bouncing (in its own thread)
  Thread gameThread;
   gameThread = new Thread() {
@Override
public void run() {
  while (true) { // Execute one update step
     // Calculate the ball's new position
     ballX += ballSpeedX;
     ballY += ballSpeedY;
     // Check if the ball moves over the bounds
     // If so, adjust the position and speed.
     if (ballX - ballRadius < 0) {
        ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX; // Reflect along normal
        ballX = ballRadius; // Re-position the ball at the edge
     } else if (ballX + ballRadius > BOX_WIDTH) {
        ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
        ballX = BOX_WIDTH - ballRadius;
     }
     // May cross both x and y bounds
     if (ballY - ballRadius < 0) {
        ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
        ballY = ballRadius;
     } else if (ballY + ballRadius > BOX_HEIGHT) {
        ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
        ballY = BOX_HEIGHT - ballRadius;
     }
     // Refresh the display
     repaint(); // Callback paintComponent()
     // Delay for timing control and give other threads a chance
     try {
        Thread.sleep(1000 / UPDATE_RATE);  // milliseconds
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
  }
}
};
  gameThread.start();  // Callback run()
}

/** Custom rendering codes for drawing the JPanel */
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);    // Paint background

  // Draw the box
  g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
  g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

  // Draw the ball
  g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
  g.fillOval((int) (ballX - ballRadius), (int) (ballY - ballRadius),
        (int)(2 * ballRadius), (int)(2 * ballRadius));
                    Graphics2D comp2D = (Graphics2D) g;                  
                    comp2D.drawRect(0, 645, 1365, 100);
                    comp2D.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    comp2D.fillRect(0, 645, 1365, 100);
                    Graphics2D stand = (Graphics2D) g;
                    stand.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    stand.fillRect(80, 575, 30, 70);
                    Graphics2D sling = (Graphics2D) g;
                    sling.drawArc(15, 570, 90, 50, 50, 250);
}

/** main program (entry point) */
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Run GUI in the Event Dispatcher Thread (EDT) instead of main thread.
  javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        // Set up main window (using Swing's Jframe)
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Angry Birds for Annie May Tion");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new BouncingBallSimple());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
     }
  });
 }
 }
```

Comment: use `BorderLayout`. for more information, please see [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).

Comment: Don't set the preferred size of your component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as removing the call to `this.setPreferredSize()` in your constructor. When the window is resized, it will request the panel to resize itself. In your paint routine, you're getting the current bounds of the panel and bouncing between them, so it should just work.

On an unrelated note: you should replace your `aameThread` with a [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). As it is, you're invoking paint requests from outside the event dispatch thread, which is a bad idea.

Comment: Nope, calling repaint() is thread safe. It is one of the few calls you can make from any thread. He also needs to change his conditions to rely on `getWidth()` and `getHeight` instead of the constants `BOX_WIDTH/BOX_HEIGHT`

Answer (score 2):

1. Drop this line: `this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT));`
2. Wherever you used `BOX_WIDTH` replace it with `getWidth()`
3. Wherever you used `BOX_HEIGHT` replace it with `getHeight()`

That should do the trick.

Comment: thank you very much. I did this, and it now works. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer here because you have hard coded x,y,w,h values.  The not-so-simple answer is to use variables instead of hard coded values and dynamically adjust those values inside the paintComponent() method.

Comment: These are using hard coded x,y,w,h values.  comp2D.drawRect(0, 645, 1365, 100);                    comp2D.fillRect(0, 645, 1365, 100);
stand.fillRect(80, 575, 30, 70);
sling.drawArc(15, 570, 90, 50, 50, 250);